# How to create a numerical count table of two variables equivalent to ggplot+geom_count() using summarise()?

Tags: r, dplyr

[image: The black dots represent count number. Because the dot size is not clear, a table with numerical values is desirable.]

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y))+ geom_count()
```

provides a plot showing the count of each [x, y] case. If there were 4 values in x and 6 values in y, geom_count would show 24 circles in a plot and each circle size representing the count.

How do I create a count table of two variables similarly using `summarise()` or any other function in dplyr? This table would show the count as a number instead of a circle size as in geom_count() for each [x, y] case.

Comment: I'm pretty confused since you started talking about plotting, and then summarizing by group, but  I think you just want to use basic `table`

Comment: summarise(.data, variable = n()) provides a count table of a single variable so I was looking for a way to manipulate this line to provide a count table of two variables.

Comment: `library(dplyr); data %>% count(x, y)`  or `table(data$x, data$y)`

Comment: data %>% count(x, y) puts both x and y variables into rows, so it creates 24 rows if there were 4 variables in x and 6 variables in y. Is there no way to display x variables in a row and y variables in a column such that I would get a table of 5 rows and 7 columns? (1 row for column names and 4 rows for x variables; 1 column for row names and 6 columns for y variables)

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are after and example of your data (`dput()`)?

Comment: R seems to be not responding when I do dput(df). The description of data can be found here. https://d18ky98rnyall9.cloudfront.net/_e34476fda339107329fc316d1f98e042_brfss_codebook.html?Expires=1558224000&Signature=ODjj3J1Xak3nkjiT5xP2cadeBNHP0hvsGjfjWS7xCpmK7uezEEAN8xdgNAdY5Ao9wpM55Kk7OlK~nqZY1YjVQk6VinMz0zIsVFoDovzrtHlUKU7-Rlc~u5hTJNngxBzSXCvC47-U4Pcp58bkXAaCiR3c0Yldlw65BJYKSq4O4ko_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. Based on your comments, I think something like this is what you are looking for:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  mpg %>% 
  mutate(
    x = cyl,
    y = drv
  )


df %>% 
  # create a column called n for number of times x & y occur together
  count(x, y) %>% 
  # create columns for each unique value of y and 
  # put the values of column n below
  spread(key = y, value = n, fill = 0) 

#     x   `4`     f     r
# ------------------------
#     4    23    58     0
#     5     0     4     0
#     6    32    43     4
#     8    48     1    21
```